# If $a+bi$ is in $E_k$ then $a-bi$ is also in $E_k$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I'm currently studying the properties of the Motzkin sets $E_k$, $k\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ of the ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.
The definition of $E_k$ is as follows: $E_0=\{0\}$, $E_1=$units of $\mathbb{Z}[i] \cup \{0\}$ and $\alpha\in E_k$ iff the map $E_{k-1}\to \dfrac{\mathbb{Z}[i]}{(\alpha)}$ is an onto map.

I don't know if my question holds true. I don't have a proof yet, that is, whenever $a+bi\in E_k$ then its conjugate is also in $E_k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prove it by induction on $k$.  The statement is true for $k=0$ and $k=1$, since $E_0=\{0\}$ and $E_1=\{0,\pm 1, \pm i\}$.  Now assume that it is true for some integer $k-1\geq 1$.  Let $\alpha\in E_k$.  This means that $E_{k-1}\to \mathbb{Z}[i]/(\alpha)$ is onto.  Now let $z\in \mathbb{Z}[i]$, and consider its complex conjugate $\overline{z}$.  By surjectivity of the map $E_{k-1}\to \mathbb{Z}[i]/(\alpha)$, there exists $\beta\in E_{k-1}$ such that $\beta-\overline{z} \in (\alpha)$.  Taking the conjugate, we get that $\overline{\beta}-z\in (\overline{\alpha})$.  By our induction hypothesis, $\overline{\beta}\in E_{k-1}$.  Hence we have proved that for any $z\in \mathbb{Z}[i]$, there exists some $\overline{\beta}\in E_{k-1}$ such that $\overline{\beta}-z\in (\overline{\alpha})$; in other words, the map $E_{k-1}\to \mathbb{Z}[i]/(\overline{\alpha})$ is surjective.  Therefore $\overline{\alpha}\in E_k$, and the statement is proved by induction.